# What does "spam" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Dawn of the Dead (1978), Frannie says this one word to Stephen.

> **SPAM**

Actually, Stephen and Frannie are hiding in the mall from zombies.

What does *spam* mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Dawn-of-the-Dead.html),

> The Troopers cautiously move into the area through the door. The
>       room is empty. The same sunrays pierce the darkness through
>       skylights. All is dead quiet. This room has no doors at all, but
>       for the one Peter opened.
>
> Roger: DOUBLE DAMN! LOOKS LIKE A FREE LUNCH, BUDDY.
>
> In the first room Stephen has started to rip open one of the cartons.
>
> Fran:  SPAM!
>
> Roger walks back into the room.
>
> Roger: YOU BRING A CAN OPENER?
>   Fran:   OH.
>   Roger:  THEN DON'T KNOCK SPAM. IT'S GOT IT'S OWN KEY.
>
> The woman flips over the can in her hand and finds the little key.

It looks like they are talking about the food product. From Wikipedia

> [Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)) (stylized SPAM) is a brand of canned precooked meat made by Hormel Foods Corporation. It was first introduced in 1937 and gained popularity worldwide after its use during World War II.

You can see it in the screenshot in OP. See, the can has a tab to open it.

[image]

---

**Edit**:  I incorrectly assumed that "key" was just another name for the tab used to pull the top off.

It refers to a device like this one

[image]

used to open the can like this

[image]

Thanks to @StoneyB for the information.